# Is it possible to use AVR programmer to program a MSP430 MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, msp430, jtag, code-composer

Is it possible to use an AVR programmer device (which supports JTAG & connects to PC via USB) to program a MSP430 MCU using its JTAG interface?
If no, why no?!? & if yes, how can integrate it with Code Composer Studio 5 ?

Answer (score 5):

Probably...

JTAG is a standard but how each chip uses (for processor debugging/loading) is different.  So if the programmer you have is generic enough then you can put an adapter or break out the signals to mate up with an msp430.  Many of the hobby level jtag adapters are essentially usb to parallel port, openocd for example if you dig down simply bit bangs that parallel interface, so it is easy to re-purpose/re-assign the signals.

I assume this is one of two things, one you want to save a buck, two you are interested in how things work at this level.  for two just google msp430 jtag and find documents like slau265j which leads you to slau320d which has the real meat of the information you need.

If you were looking to save a buck, dont, just get the msp430 launchpad for $4.30 (I dont think there is a shipping charge).  Pull the jumpers off and just use the two signals and ground and power if you need it to program your part.  You can put your part if it is a dip in the launchpad (if it fits/mates) and program it that way or disconnect the jumpers and use the signals off the jumper pins or order the mill-max 850-10-006-20-001000 connectors and solder them on (makes it work like a ez430).  (or get an ez430 kit for $20)  I use the launchpad front end with the mill max connector to program the 3 boards for $10 ez430 boards using mspdebug.

Getting this all integrated into code composer studio 5?  I have no clue how to help you there.